# How does the ABFS Driver in Databricks read blobs in Azure Data Lake?

Tags: hadoop, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using Databricks to access data in Azure Data Lake Gen2 using the ABFS driver.  I want to verify my understanding of how this is working behind the scenes.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction#key-features-of-data-lake-storage-gen2):

> Hadoop compatible access: Data Lake Storage Gen2 allows you to manage and access data just as you would with a Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). The new ABFS driver (used to access data) is available within all Apache Hadoop environments. These environments include Azure HDInsight, Azure Databricks, and Azure Synapse Analytics.

I understand this to mean that the ABFS driver reads multiple blocks of a blob sitting in ADLS in parallel.  This provides greater performance, as opposed to a traditional file system where you'd be limited by individual file I/O.

Am I interpreting how this is working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Azure Storage Blob driver or WASB driver provided the original support for Azure Blob Storage. This driver performed the complex task of mapping file system semantics (as required by the Hadoop FileSystem interface) to that of the object store style interface exposed by Azure Blob Storage. This driver continues to support this model, providing high performance access to data stored in blobs, but contains a significant amount of code performing this mapping, making it difficult to maintain. Additionally, some operations such as FileSystem.rename() and FileSystem.delete() when applied to directories require the driver to perform a vast number of operations (due to object stores lack of support for directories) which often leads to degraded performance. The ABFS driver was designed to overcome the inherent deficiencies of WASB.

(1) **File System.** There is a terminology difference with ADLS Gen2. The concept of a container (from blob storage) is referred to as a file system in ADLS Gen2.

(2) **Hierarchical Namespace.** The hierarchical namespace (HNS), coupled with the DFS endpoint, is what enables the performance and security improvements.

(3) **DFS Endpoint and File System Driver.** ADLS Gen2 utilizes the ABFS driver, which is part of Apache Hadoop. For connectivity to ADLS Gen2, the ABFS driver utilizes the DFS endpoint to invoke performance and security optimizations.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p abfs://fileanalysis@myanalytics.dfs.core.windows.net/tutorials/flightdelays/data
hdfs dfs -put flight_delays.csv abfs://fileanalysis@myanalytics.dfs.core.windows.net/tutorials/flightdelays/data/
```

**Internally, the ABFS driver translates the resource(s) specified in the URI to files and directories and makes calls to the Azure Data Lake Storage REST API with those references.**

The hierarchical file system model (ADLS Gen1 and Gen2) are compatible with HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System). This is achieved with drivers that implement server-side HDFS semantics to translate into remote storage APIs, allowing ADLS Gen2 to behave very similarly to native HDFS.
Features of ABFS driver:-

(1) **Query Performance.** When sending a query that is only retrieving a subset of data, with a hierarchical file system like ADLS Gen2 it is possible to leverage partition scans for data pruning (predicate pushdown). This can improve query performance dramatically for compute engines that understand how to take advantage of partition scans.

(2) **Data Load Performance.** Sometimes it is necessary to rename files or relocate files from one directory to another.
With the object store driver, directory operations are not handled as efficiently. If the Temp directory shown in the below image held 10,000 files, relocating them to their permanent directory would involve 10,000 rename operations and 10,000 delete operations, resulting in 20,000 calls.

Conversely, with a file system like ADLS Gen2, when connecting through the DFS endpoint this is a metadata-only operation. This results in significantly improved performance for the data load, particularly at higher data volumes.
In addition to improving query performance, metadata-only operations are ultimately more cost-effective because less compute engine resources are required.

(3) **Data Consistency via Atomic Operations.** For example, if 10,000 files to be moved, the object store driver does not support atomic operations. If a failure occurred, the data could remain in an inconsistent state.

Conversely, a file system like ADLS Gen2 does support atomic operations, via the DFS endpoint, which improves data consistency because the entire operation will succeed or fail as a unit.

For more details follow - [The Azure Blob Filesystem driver (ABFS): A dedicated Azure Storage driver for Hadoop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-abfs-driver)

Also refer - [Things to know about azure data lake storage gen2](https://www.bluegranite.com/blog/10-things-to-know-about-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2)

Comment: thank you for the detailed response, however this does not answer the specific question asked above